# MATLAB: Transferring variables between script and GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am new to using GUIDE and using GUIs in Matlab.

I am running a script in Matlab that will accept initial inputs from the user and then proceed to open up a GUI (created with GUIDE) which will accept further inputs from the user. However, I cannot figure out a way to transfer variables and data between my script and my GUI. I am aware that script variables/data and GUI variables/data are saved in different workspaces; I just need some simple way to communicate between the two.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into GUI Handles. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guihandles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to use [setappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and getappdata in order to store your variables/input/whatever so that it's accessible from wherever you want.

Let's say you delcare some variable in your script that you want to retrieve in your GUI:

```
A = rand(100,100);
```

Then using setappdata like the following:

```
setappdata(0,'VariableName',A);
```

will store the data in the root directory (the 0 as the 1st input), meaning that using getappdata like this in the GUI:

```
A_in_GUI = getappdata(0,'VariableName');
```

will allow you to retrieve the value from your GUI, or from any other script as long as you use the correct variable names of course. Notice that you can use a handle to some figure/GUI where you could save your data, like this;

```
setappdata(handles.Something,'VariableName','A);
```

but if you close the figure, for instance, you might not be able to retrieve your variable.

As Tyler pointed out, a nice way to share data between different callbacks inside your GUI is to use its handles structure. More info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html).

Final Note:

If you don't want to spend your time sharing many variables between scripts and GUIs, you can store all of your variables in a single large structure and use setappdata/getappdata only on this structure, which will keep all your variables updated.

For instance, you can write something like this in the script:

```
Variables_Structure.MyFavoriteNumber = pi;
Variables_Structure.MyFavoriteSport = 'ice hockey';

setappdata(0,'MyVariables',Variables_Structure);
```

and then getappdata in the GUI in which you want to use the variables:

```
Variables_in_GUI = getappdata(0,'MyVariables');
```

Comment: Great! If it helped you solve you problem, could you mark my answer as "Accepted" by clicking the green tick mark please? Thanks!